# RYU openflow controller error noted with python

Tags: python

Its interesting after I did "python ./setup.py install" on an ubuntu machine, and I'm seeing a bind error as the openflow controller initiates. I double checked there's no application or services hogging port "8080"

```
ryu-manager ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py
loading app ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py
loading app ryu.controller.ofp_handler
instantiating app None of DPSet
creating context dpset
creating context wsgi
instantiating app ryu.controller.ofp_handler of OFPHandler
instantiating app ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py of RestStatsApi
hub: uncaught exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 48, in _launch
func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/controller/controller.py", line 65, in __call__
self.server_loop()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/controller/controller.py", line 88, in      server_loop
datapath_connection_factory)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 85, in __init__
self.server = eventlet.listen(listen_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 38, in listen
sock.bind(addr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Now, one another machine, which is running python 2.6, this runs fine

```
ryu-manager ~/ryu/ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py
loading app /root/ryu/ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py
loading app ryu.controller.ofp_handler
creating context dpset
creating context wsgi
instantiating app /root/ryu/ryu/app/ofctl_rest.py
instantiating app ryu.controller.ofp_handler
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, port 8080 was not the area of contention but rather it was 6633. I had forgotten to remove my OVS OpenFlow settings

```
sudo lsof -i :6633
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ovs-contr 1620 root    4u  IPv4   9071      0t0  TCP *:6633 (LISTEN)
```